# How to get commit author name and email with gitpython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

When I run `git log`, I get the this line for each commit: "Author: name < email >". How do I get the exact same format for a commit in Python for a local repo? When I run the code below, I get just the author name.

```
from git import Repo

repo_path = 'mockito'
repo = Repo(repo_path)

commits_list = list(repo.iter_commits())

for i in range(5):
    commit = commits_list[i]

    print(commit.hexsha)
    print(commit.author)
    print(commit.committer)
```

Comment: There are multiple, differing Python wrapper packages for Git. Which one are you using?

Comment: gitpython. Which would you reommend?

Comment: I have no recommendations, but if package A does it in Way A, and package B does it in Way B, an answer telling you about Way B does you no good if you're using package A. Always put enough detail into your question so that your question has a specific answer.

Comment: I can use any package mentioned in any answer. So, any answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

According to [the gitpython API documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html), a [commit object](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.objects.commit.Commit)—an instance of `class git.objects.commit.Commit`—has `author` and `committer` attributes that are instances of [`class git.util.Actor`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.util.Actor), which in turn has fields `conf_email`, `conf_name`, `email`, and `name`.

Hence (untested):

```
print(commit.author.name, commit.author.email)
```

will likely get you the two fields you want, though you may wish to format them in some way.

**Edit**: I'll defer to [Gino Mempin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58550510/1256452) since I don't have gitpython installed to test this.

Comment: It does work: `print(f"Author: {commit.author.name}: {commit.author.email}")`. I did not look past the `author` object :|

Answer (score 6):

<strike>It seems that gitpython's `Commit` objects do not have an attribute for the author email.</strike>

You can also use gitpython to [call git commands directly](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly). You can use the [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) command, passing in the commit HASH (from `commit.hexsha`) and then a [`--format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) option that gives you just the author's name and email (you can of course pass other format options you need).

Using plain git:

```sh
$ git show -s --format='%an <%ae>' 4e13ccfbde2872c23aec4f105f334c3ae0cb4bf8
me <me@somewhere.com>
```

Using gitpython to [use git directly](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly):

```py
from git import Repo

repo_path = 'myrepo'
repo = Repo(repo_path)

commits_list = list(repo.iter_commits())
for i in range(5):
    commit = commits_list[i]

    author = repo.git.show("-s", "--format=Author: %an <%ae>", commit.hexsha)
    print(author)
```